# Unable to switch context from native app to web view

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am doing some automation with Appium on a iOS mobile app.

I need to:

open the app
do some tasks
open safari
do some tasks
Switch back to app
Do some tasks

However, I am unable to switch the context from native app to web view in step 3.

Tried using activateapp(bundle id) but with this when i am driver.getContext() I am only getting native_app.

Comment: try this [switch context](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/54c2b4e6500eddbca4bb3047116ceb8d177f7294/docs/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid.md)